# SSIS string to datetime datatype

Tags: ssis

I am working with a DataFlow Task. All the data is being transferred from source file to destination database without any issue except a single column - "HostDT_TM" The order of tasks in my package are
Tasks
**1. Flat file source**: a dat file

Value of HostDT_TM = 01-MAY-2017 11:01:00.00

Data type: DT_STR

**2. Script Component**
Performing the following step and converting the source column to required datetime format:

```
 DateTime outputHostDT_TM = DateTime.ParseExact(Row.HostDT_TM, "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.ff"
, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Datatype of Output Column at this step : DT_DBTIMESTAMP

**3. Data Conversion**

Input Column: outputHostDT_TM

Datatype : DT_DBTIMESTAMP

Output Column: : outputHostDT_TM

Datatype : DT_DBTIMESTAMP

**4. OLE DB Destination**

Destination External Columns: outputHostDT_TM

Datatype : DT_DBTIMESTAMP

Input Columns: I don't find outputHostDT_TM column in the list. As for my understanding 
the input column here should be the output column of data conversion task(if im not wrong)
However i see HostDT_TM in the list with data type DT_STR

The package is failing at step 4, OLE DB Destination step saying due to potential loss of data.

I added a multicast task between step 3 and 4 and the error being displayed under outputHostDT_TM cloumn is 
Error: Year, Month, and Date parameters describe an unrepresentable DateTime.

Comment: What is the purpose of Step 3?   You say it's a data conversion, but the input column and datatype are exactly the same as the output.   When you put a dataviewer on the output of step 2, what do you see?

Comment: I am using Data Conversion for the purpose of other columns in my package. Yes, it doesn't make any changes to HOSTDT_TM column. On the output of step 2 the data viewer is showing the same error message  Error: Year, Month, and Date parameters describe an unrepresentable DateTime.

Comment: your input and output columns in step 3 have same name?   When you look at the Metadata coming out of step 2 (doubleclick the line coming from the Script component), does it have DT_DBTIMESTAMP or DT_STR? Not sure what you were looking at to confirm the datatype you list, maybe it was the Metadata

Comment: Does the error occur if you try it with a flat file that only has one row, and the value of HostDT_TM = 01-MAY-2017 11:01:00.00?   Can you post a screenshot of a data viewer of this data after the flat file source?